# Load whole page

Tags: javascript, html

This may seem like a basic question.

I have a light-weight website and would like to load the whole page at once, so that links to the Home/Contact/... parts of the website will take no time to load.

What would be the best mechanism to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have setup a basic jsfiddle to show how this can be achieved with jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/9DMBq/

Basically I created this kind of context with html and css:

the css:

```
<style>
#container { height: 200px; width: 400px; background-color: #CCC; }
h3 { font-size: 20px; padding:5px; }

.button {cursor: pointer; padding:10px; background-color: #EEE; margin:5px;}

.content { position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFF}
​</style>
```

the html:

```
<div id="container">
<span id="homenav" class="button">Home</span>
<span id="aboutnav" class="button">About</span>
<br>
</br>
<div id="home" class="content">
    <h3>home</h3>
</div>
<div id="about" class="content" style="display: none;">
    <h3>about</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

and then I added some Jquery to make it work:

```
$('.button').click(function() {

    var whereto = $(this).attr("id").replace('nav', '')

    $('.content').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#' + whereto).fadeIn()
    })
})​
```

I hope this solves your problem although there are many other ways to do this.

​

I originally thought you were referring to having the page only show once all the content had finished loading, however i'll leave this here just incase;

This can be accomplished super easy with jquery with the following code

make sure to reference jquery in the header with :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and then stick the following in the head of your html

```
<script>
    $('html').hide();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('html').show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I misunderstood the question at first, as I think you did. He wants to load all of the pages ahead of time and just show them right away when a link is clicked.

Comment: Updated it with a solution c:

Answer (score 3):

Load those pages into invisible DIVs and then just show/hide them via Javascript when user clicks links.

Comment: That sounds simple enough. What script would I need for this? I tried the example from MagicDev without success...

Comment: My 'example' is an example of this fyi

Answer (score 0):

[window.onload](http://roberthahn.ca/articles/2007/02/02/how-to-use-window-onload-the-right-way/) -< A good place to start

```
window.onload = function() { /* do everything */
```

after that look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s .[show](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aBasic_Show_and_Hide)() and use css display: none